# Referencing another .wxs file in my Product.wxs

Tags: wix, windows-installer, heat

I generated a heat.exe output to include so basic executable in my main installer package. The heat output "heat.exe is in a seperate folder. The problem is I don't know how to reference them in my main "FP7000TestApp.wxs" file. I'm working on command line not VS. Code Below:

This is what I tried to do`

```
<Fragment>
  <ComponentGroup Id="EXEs">
    <ComponentRef Id="cmpBBBEC31C5B1E1F507A5D59DBD596512D" />
    <ComponentRef Id="cmp858C0D92FD93990FC130F9E9AD2EDF23" />
    <ComponentRef Id="cmp3A6B57CB085F639B66098D25C095A639" />
  </ComponentGroup>
</Fragment>
<Fragment>
  <DirectoryRef Id="INSTALLDIR">
    <Directory Id="dirCF50D58BC65CC93005501980AACC3EDD" Name="Included Apps">
      <Component Id="cmpBBBEC31C5B1E1F507A5D59DBD596512D" Guid="{E088F199-5139-4109-B2DD-83ACF994E499}">
        <File Id="fil4FBD990F67A018822444D44D411F9144" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\FP7000-Camera App.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp858C0D92FD93990FC130F9E9AD2EDF23" Guid="{811D9046-0C67-4352-87C2-CFE5C242C9C6}">
        <File Id="fil795D8B9538A78888D097D1AFAF3881D3" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\install_cmds.exe" />
      </Component>
      <Component Id="cmp3A6B57CB085F639B66098D25C095A639" Guid="{177B954A-CA1A-4AF4-BACB-BCB5B1E7B4BF}">
        <File Id="fil1FD260547094E801231BFA5E75AE4E57" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Intel_Media_SDK_2016_R2.msi" />
      </Component>
    </Directory>
  </DirectoryRef>
</Fragment>`
```

I then later try to add these files to the INSTALLDIR:

```
<Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
    <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
      <Directory Id="INSTALLDIR" Name="Stryker_Corp">
        <Component Id="cmpBBBEC31C5B1E1F507A5D59DBD596512D" Guid="{E088F199-5139-4109-B2DD-83ACF994E499}">
          <File Id="fil4FBD990F67A018822444D44D411F9144" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\FP7000-Camera App.exe" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmp858C0D92FD93990FC130F9E9AD2EDF23" Guid="{811D9046-0C67-4352-87C2-CFE5C242C9C6}">
          <File Id="fil795D8B9538A78888D097D1AFAF3881D3" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\install_cmds.exe" />
        </Component>
        <Component Id="cmp3A6B57CB085F639B66098D25C095A639" Guid="{177B954A-CA1A-4AF4-BACB-BCB5B1E7B4BF}">
          <File Id="fil1FD260547094E801231BFA5E75AE4E57" KeyPath="yes" Source="SourceDir\Intel_Media_SDK_2016_R2.msi" />
        </Component>
         </Directory>
       </Directory>
     </Directory>
```

Answer (score 3):

I have checked my auto-generated output from Visual Studio and looks like you need to add `-ext "X:\path\to\file\heatfile.wxs"` to `candle.exe` call

and

`-spdb "obj\Debug\heatfile.wixobj"` to `Light.exe` call.

Then just reference Component group in your main product file feature list

```
<Feature Id=...>
      <ComponentGroupRef Id="EXEs" />   
</Feature>
```